# How can I make multiple spans equal width within a div

Tags: css, html

Say I have the following:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width:300px;">
<span style="background: red; width:100px;">one</span>
<span style="background: yellow; width:100px;">two</span>
<span style="background: red; width:100px;">three</span>
</div>
```

What CSS can I apply to make the spans equally spaced within the div?

Comment: Is your intent for the outer container to be fixed to 300px or for the inner spans to just be evenly width'd?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to strongly disagree with the other answers, suggesting `inline-block` and `float:left` as these solutions will give you a floating layout.  This may be fine most of the time, I have seen cases where 33.33% + 33.33% + 33.33% > 100%, usually on Android devices.  This pushes the last cell onto the next line.

Since you are trying to create a tabular appearance, I would recommend using tabular display styles:

```css
        #myTable {
            display: table;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 300px;
        }
        
        #myTable > * {
            display: table-cell;
            width: 33.33%;
        }
```

```html
<div id="myTable">
  <span style="background: red">one</span>
  <span style="background: yellow">two</span>
  <span style="background: red">three</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Brian, funnily enough - in the end I encountered the same issue you mention here. I also ended up using a table to solve it. Pity though cos I really wanted to not use a table.

Comment: You're not using a table, you're just telling the browser to display the spans as they would display a table. The key difference being that the html isn't actually a table, so screen-readers and web crawlers and other "blind" visitors don't assume it's tabular data. The other benefit, as will all css, is that if you decide to display it some other way, you change the css, not the html.  But I do agree it's a pity you can't just say "width: 1/3".

Answer (score 3):

`Spans` are inline elements and have the width of their respective contents. If you want to set a specific width, use block elements like `div` or `p` and arrange them horizontally with `float:left;`

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width:300px;">
   <div style="float:left; background: red; width:100px;">one</div>
   <div style="float:left; background: yellow; width:100px;">two</div>
   <div style="float:left; background: red; width:100px;">three</div>
</div>
```

Generally speaking, `span` is used for formatting purposes, like setting font style, etc. Block elements like `div` can be used for layout and positioning.

You can tweak `spans` to do the same, but it's not recommended. `Divs` are there for this exact purpose.

Comment: alternatively I think you can add the style `display:inline-block` to the `<span>` however I'm sure this is frowned upon and also probably not cross-browser safe :0

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'float:left;' style to your span.

Answer (score 0):

```
   span {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 33.33%;
     text-align: center;
   }
```

This should work, removing each 100px width you have in your spans. Spans are by default inline elements, so applying a width property directly to them has no effect. First you have to "blockalize" them. If you have some problem with some browser with the `display: inline-block;`, you can use `float: left;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, I would strongly advice against using styling inline with your HTML. You should try to keep things separated, and styling belongs in your CSS file/files.

Also, try looking into a grid system, that makes this kind of formatting much easier and maintainable. Good examples are:

http://960.gs/

http://cssgrid.net/

or

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ (a full CSS framework that adds some extra features)

There are several others, just posting these as examples.